# Integrate Google Maps autocomplete in an Angularjs Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I want to implement [THIS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) functionality within my Angularjs app:

[image]

That is, autofill certain input boxes based on the input from one input. I thought it would be a neat idea to integrate it in a AngularJs directive using $scope only by adding a directive call within my inputbox.

```
<input type="text" name="searchAdress" googleplace>
```

*googleplace.js*

```
app.directive('googleplace', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {
        var options = {
            types: [],
            componentRestrictions: {}
        };
        $scope.address = ....
        $scope.city =....
        $scope.country = ....
        ....
       }
    };
});
```

Is there a way to do this? Can define functions, just as in the API-description, within my directives or is there another way to handle this?